# How to add emoji to my HTML on Win 7?

Tags: html

I've added some emoji symbols to my HTML code on MAC (just cut and paste them). They show perfect on mac, iphone, ipad, some android devices, even in windows 8.1 it works almost normal, but on win 7 they don't show at all. 
Is there some way to make them visible?

P. S. I can't use images instead of them.

Comment: You could to use a webfont as fallback, but those fallbacks can be only monochrom.

Comment: Maybe there is some unicode for this symbols and it will work better.

Comment: The emoji that show cross device are encoded in unicode. That's why you could use a webfont providing those icons as fallback. [Emoji Unicode Tables](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-1-emoticons)

Answer (score 0):

You could see them on Windows 8.1 because they were included in the default UI symbol font.  Windows 7 does not support these characters.  You can update the [Segoe UI symbol font](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2729094?wa=wsignin1.0) and it should then work, but that's only on your local machine, not anyone else's that might visit the page.